# The curvature of line of intersection of 2 surfaces.

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

The problem is as follows.

Let $S_1$=$x^2+y^2-z^2=1, z>0$ and $S_2=z^2-2x+y=0$. And define $c$ is curve which is line of intersection of $S_1$ and $S_2$. Find the curvature of $C$ at $P=(1,1,1) $

I tried to parametrization of C by calculating $S_1$ and $S_2$ BUT it has the root on z-axis, i think it may have problem about regularity ...
In fact, i calculate $x= 1+$$ 3\over 2$$cost$ and $y=$$-1 \over 2$ $+$ $3 \over 2$ $sint$... please the full explanation the solution of this problem.

Comment: You forgot to find $z(t)$. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin I find the coordinate expressions of  z-axis but it has form of consisting of root.. i asked this because it may have problem of regularity of c. I'd like to know another expressions of z-axis or another method of soloving this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far we found

$x(t) = 1 + \frac{3}{2} \cos t$

$y(t) = -\frac{1}{2} + \frac{3}{2} \sin t$

Substituting in any of $S1$ or $S2$, we get

$z(t)^2 = \frac{5}{2} + 3 \cos t - \frac{3}{2} \sin t$

So, $z(t) = \sqrt{\frac{5}{2} + 3 \cos t - \frac{3}{2} \sin t}$

$r(t) = (1 + \frac{3}{2} \cos t, -\frac{1}{2} + \frac{3}{2} \sin t, \sqrt{\frac{5}{2} + 3 \cos t - \frac{3}{2} \sin t} \,)$

$r'(t) = (-\frac{3}{2} \sin t, \frac{3}{2} \cos t, - \frac{3(\sin t + \frac{1}{2} \cos t)} {2 \, \sqrt{\frac{5}{2} + 3 \cos t - \frac{3}{2} \sin t}} \, \,)$

$r''(t) = (-\frac{3}{2} \cos t, -\frac{3}{2} \sin t, -\frac{3(\cos t - \frac{1}{2} \sin t)} {2 \, \sqrt{\frac{5}{2} + 3 \cos t - \frac{3}{2} \sin t}} - \frac{9(\sin t + \frac{1}{2} \cos t)^2} {4 \, (\frac{5}{2} + 3 \cos t - \frac{3}{2} \sin t)^{3/2}} \, \,)$

Using $r(t)$, we know that at point $(1, 1, 1), t = \frac{\pi}{2}$.

So, $r'(t) = (-\frac{3}{2}, 0, -\frac{3}{2})$

$|r'(t)| = \frac{3}{\sqrt2}$

$r''(t) = (0, -\frac{3}{2}, -\frac{3}{2})$

Curvature $k = \displaystyle \frac{|r'(t) \times {r''(t)}|}{|r'(t)|^3}$

Cross product of $r'(t)$ and ${r''(t)} = (-\frac{9}{4}, -\frac{9}{4}, \frac{9}{4})$

$|r'(t) \times {r''(t)}| = \frac{9 \sqrt3}{4}$

So, curvature $k = \frac{1}{\sqrt 6}$

Comment: THANKS. I have a question. Is the formula valid for revolution?

Comment: Is the curvature independent for z-axis?? I'd like to know how the formula is consisted of x and y

Comment: oh! Thanks. Then, is the curvature 2/3 not root 2/3?  May i understand the curvature is curvature of circle in xy-plane with radius 3/2?

Comment: This is WRONG. The intersection curve has a $z$-coordinate that varies with $t$ as well!! You're both making the standard mistake of eliminating a variable and forgetting to substitute to solve for it later!

Comment: @TedShifrin thanks a lot for pointing out. I had not forgotten about $z$ but I got a constant value of $z$ when I substituted back in one of the curves so of course I was doing some calculation mistake or was in a hurry to assume so.

Comment: @Math Lover how was when $5 \over 2$ $+3cost-$$3 \over 2$ $sint=0$? I asked this point.

Comment: @Math Lover no. I'm not asking the formula.. i just ask that 'is it possible that the expressions on z-axis  including z-axis? If 5/2~sint=0, the parametrization has error??

Comment: If I understand your question right, the definition of curvature requires that the curve is continuously differentiable near a point. It is near $(1, 1, 1)$ but not necessarily at all points. At the point where $\frac{5}{2} + 3 \cos t - \frac{3}{2} \sin t = 0$, it has no meaning. Please read Plain Curves section of wiki. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature.